# How can I find a reason that a program stalls?

Tags: linux, debugging, segmentation-fault, controls

I'm handling a program which controls a car.
The program has a pretty large scale and it was made by other people.
So I don't understand completely how it works.
But I have to apply it and make a car moving.

The problem I'm facing is that the program often stalls with no error, no segmentation.

If it crashes, I can trace the cause with gdb or something like that.

But it does not crash, it silently stops.

How can I find the cause?

Comment: This is way too broad. There are many ways, from adding print statements, to adding debugger break points, and just reasoning about the code. Basically, any standard debugging technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description - program silently stops - I understand that your program simply and gracefully exited, but not from your expected flow. 
This can happen for many reasons - for example, maybe your program enters illegal flow and some sub-component, such as standard library or other library decide that program should exit, and thus calls c-runtime `exit()` or directly calls `Kernel32!ExitProcess()`.
The best way to debug this flow is to attach a debugger and set a breakpoint on these two methods and find out who is calling them.
If you mean your program enters a deadlock and halts then also you will need to attach a debugger and find out who is stuck.